# Upgrading my application to include prepopulated data

Tags: swift, core-data

I've decided to improve upon my initial design and pre-populate certain parts of my Application. I am trying to get the sqlite to be read following this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/core-data-preload-sqlite-database/

However the line of code that goes like this:

```
if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(url.path!) {
    let sourceSqliteURLs =         [NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("CoreDataDemo", withExtension: "sqlite")!, NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("CoreDataDemo", withExtension: "sqlite-wal")!, NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("CoreDataDemo", withExtension: "sqlite-shm")!]

    let destSqliteURLs =   [self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("CoreDataDemo.sqlite"),
        self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("CoreDataDemo.sqlite-wal"),
        self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("CoreDataDemo.sqlite-shm")]

    var error:NSError? = nil
    for var index = 0; index < sourceSqliteURLs.count; index++ {
        NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL(sourceSqliteURLs[index], toURL: destSqliteURLs[index], error: &error)
    }
}
```

isn't quite right for my application as I am using a shared application folder. The problem I am facing is that the application loads fine and passes the lines of code but when I am looking at the page that shows the info nothing is there. I downloaded the sqlite reader to see if there are objects in the database and there are so I know that isn't the issue. What modifications do I have to make to these lines of code in order for the share app group to perform this function correctly? The directory to the Shared App Group is something like this:

```
let directory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.groupname.appname")
```

I am struggling to find any info on this any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something in your questions, but if all you want to do is change the destination directory, then just change these lines...

```
let destSqliteURLs = [
    self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("CoreDataDemo.sqlite"),
    self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("CoreDataDemo.sqlite-wal"),
    self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("CoreDataDemo.sqlite-shm")]
```

into this...

```
let baseURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.groupname.appname")
let destSqliteURLs = [
    baseURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("CoreDataDemo.sqlite"),
    baseURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("CoreDataDemo.sqlite-wal"),
    baseURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("CoreDataDemo.sqlite-shm")]
```

Comment: I tried doing this, this morning but to no success. For whatever reason the store isn't actually loading this change? The application doesn't seem to recognize these changes and just loads a blank store as though nothing happened. I can't see what I am doing wrong as I updated the syntax correctly for swift 2 as well and verified the store actually contains base data.